# what is "terminal" option in Angular Directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

how can I use priority and terminal in my directives?

```
myModule.directive('Directive1', function() {
        return {
            priority: 1,
            terminal: false,
            link: function() {
                console.log("this is directive 1");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terminal and priority use with each other. if you are going to discard other directives in AngularJS, use `terminal: true`.

**Be careful:**

Directives should be in the same element

For example, you have three directive options as follows:

```
directive1:{
    priority:1,
    terminal:false
}

directive2:{
    priority:2,
    terminal:false
}

directive3:{
    priority:3,
    terminal:true
}
```

`<dr-name directive-1 directive-2 directive-3></dr-name>`

In this example just the directive3 execute.

**Note:**

If the terminal will be true then directives with lower priority don't execute.(either their terminal is true or false)